# How to make custom tool-tip/pop-up

Tags: android

I'm working on kind of tool-tip which I suppose has to be a custom pop-up.
The tool-tip is an image, appears ones when application is started. The image has to be shown on specific location and closed when user touches a screen and never shown again.

I've started with style.xml file in res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomDialotTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/hint</item>    
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

in .java:

```
public class ShopListActivity extends Activity {
static Activity _activity;
ListView _list;
ListView _listLocation;
ShopListAdapter _adapter;
HashMap<Object, StoreRow> _storesMap = new HashMap<Object, StoreRow>();
HashMap<Object, StoreRow> _storesMapLocation = new HashMap<Object, StoreRow>();

private Button _buttonGetLocation;
private Button _buttonSortAll;
private LocationManager _locManager;
private LocationListener _locListener;
private boolean _gpsEnabled = false;
private boolean _networkEnabled = false;
// hashmap table indication: false - use storeMap, true - use
// storesMapLocation
private boolean _loadByLocation = false;
double _longitude;
double _latitude;
Location currentLocation;
// set fonts
Typeface font;
Typeface fontBold;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shops_view);
    // get custom fonts
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rutz_oereg.ttf");
    fontBold = Typeface
            .createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rutz_oebol.otf");

    loadMyProductsList();

    // delete product that are older then 7 days
    deleteOldProducts();

    _list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    _list.setDivider(null);
    _list.setDividerHeight(0);
    _list.setCacheColorHint(0);
    // for the search by location
    _buttonGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter_location);
    _buttonGetLocation.setOnClickListener(gpsListener);
    _buttonGetLocation.setPressed(false);
    // set custom font
    _buttonGetLocation.setTypeface(fontBold);
            _longitude = Constants.sortByPrioritiesLocation;
    _latitude = Constants.sortByPrioritiesLocation;
    _buttonSortAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter_all);
    _buttonSortAll.setOnClickListener(sortAllListener);
    _buttonSortAll.setPressed(true);
    // set cunstom font
    _buttonSortAll.setTypeface(fontBold);

    _adapter = new ShopListAdapter(this, _storesMap);
    LoadStoresTask task = new LoadStoresTask();
    task.execute(new Void[] {});

    Button btnMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMore);
    btnMore.setOnClickListener(moreStoresListener);
    //set custom fonts
    btnMore.setTypeface(fontBold);

    _activity = ShopListActivity.this;
            Dialog _hintDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialotTheme);
            _hintDialog.setContentView(R.layout.shops_view);
            _hintDialog.setCancelable(false);
            _hintDialog.show();
}
```

It never shows up.
Maybe there is another way to create a tool-tip or appreciate any suggestion how to create a custom pop-up I need.

Comment: Your code seems right. Where did you use this code? Show full java code here?

Comment: The problem is I reload activity when click on sorting buttons. It seems like when the tool tip shown up it would be started each time when activity reloads. Is there any object that could be created ones per application running? Thanks, the code is updated (see above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [tutorial](http://www.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid)

It will definitely help you.

Njoy!!

Comment: Thanks. Do you think a pop-up might be a good solution in this case?